# Scala repeated sorting in the result

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD containing "Customer", "Amt spent". I am trying to perform a simple sorting to order by "Amt Spent". When i view the results, i see multiple sorting happening.

- **My code:**

  ```
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "TotalSpentByCustomerSorted")   

  val input = sc.textFile("filename.csv")

  val input2 = input.map(line=>line.split(",")).map(
    line=>(line(0).toInt,line(2).toFloat)
  ) // To fetch only customer#, Amt spent

  val input3 = input2.reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y)).sortBy(x=>x._2)

  input3.foreach(println)
  ```
- **Result:**

  ```
  (28,5000.7104)
  (22,5019.449)
  (29,5032.5303)
  (17,5032.6797)
  (60,5040.7095)
  (45,3309.3804)
  (79,3790.5698)
  (96,3924.23)
  (23,4042.65)
  (99,4172.29)
  ```

As you can see from the result, first 5 entries are sorted by Amt spent, and then again another sorting happens. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the sorted did nit worked, but that you called a `println()` inside a `foreach` on a **RDD** - that operation is performed on parallel on all partitions.
And, on a real cluster *(not in a local environment for development)* you would not even see the printed lines, because those would happen on the executors' **JVMs**.

The **RDD** is sorted, but if you don't want to believe me *(that would be smart)*, then you may perform a `collect` before the `foreach`, that would fetch all results to the driver first and then print them *(it will fetch them in the order they are)*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believed that as I am running in local dev environment, there is no partition concept and hence, there is no parallel process of tasks. By adding collect, it worked as expected.